# Mockito exectues "when-then" from previous test

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

When I run these tests separetly, they work just fine but when I execute "run all tests in class", then test shouldSaveProduct fails. I get exception("DataIntegrityViolationException") which is specified in previous test. It looks like `Mockito.when(productRepositoryMock.save(any())).thenReturn(product);` does not override:

```
Mockito.when(productRepositoryMock.save(any())).thenThrow(new DataIntegrityViolationException("...SYMBOL_UQ..."));
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class ProductServiceImplTest {

    private ProductService productService;
    private ProductRepository productRepositoryMock;

    @BeforeAll
    void setup() {
        productRepositoryMock = Mockito.mock(ProductRepository.class);
        productService = new ProductServiceImpl(productRepositoryMock);
    }
    
    @Test
    void shouldThrowProductExceptionBecauseOfDuplicateSymbol() {
        // given
        Product product = new Product();
        Mockito.when(productRepositoryMock.save(any()))
                .thenThrow(new DataIntegrityViolationException("...SYMBOL_UQ..."));
        // when && then
        ProductException exception = Assertions.assertThrows(ProductException.class, () ->
                productService.saveProduct(product), "Expected to throw ProductException");
        assertEquals(ProductExceptionMessage.SYMBOL_MUST_BE_UNIQUE, exception.getMessage());
    }
    
    @Test
    void shouldSaveProduct() {
        // given
        Product product = getProduct();
        Mockito.when(productRepositoryMock.save(any())).thenReturn(product);
        // when
        ProductTO resultProduct = productService.saveProduct(product);
        // then
        assertEquals(product.getName(), resultProduct.getName());
    }
}
```

When I use `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)` and `@BeforeEach`, then it works but I don't understand why it doesn't work with configuration presented above. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

Because this line

```
 @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
```

Its make Junit create one instance of the test class and reuse it between tests.

Comment: Normally, `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)` is default value, you can delete this line and it must still work fine.